# How to create a loss plot from loaded weights? (model.load_weights) How to add model.load_weights to history?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, loss-function, faster-rcnn

I would like to create a loss. (plot) I use Mask-RCNN. I loaded a weights from my model. But I can't create a loss function. I got error: `'Model' object has no attribute 'history'`

```
model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="training",
                          config=config,
                          model_dir=ROOT_DIR)

model.load_weights('/my/path/to/mask_rcnn_0007.h5', by_name=True)
model.load_weights(''/my/path/to/mask_rcnn_0008.h5'', by_name=True)
model.load_weights(''/my/path/to/mask_rcnn_0009.h5'', by_name=True)
model.load_weights(''/my/path/to/mask_rcnn_0010.h5'', by_name=True)
model.load_weights(''/my/path/to/mask_rcnn_0011.h5'.h5', by_name=True)


history = model.keras_model.history.history
```

Comment: I shoutdown my jupyter notebook and restarted. I lost my plots (loss, val loss...) , which I want to use. It takes a lot of hours and I don't want start kernel again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use tensorboard

> $ tensorboard --logdir logs/

logs/ -->use your folder where you save your .h5 files

> you should see something like this in your browser, using https://127.0.0.1:6006/ .

[image: tensorboard]